# what am i doing wrong with my while true try except else loop

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop, break, try-except

im trying to get my bot to go onto a website and if the website is down or not running properly for my bot to reload the page, and to loop that until it finds the clickable element by xpath, and then to continue on. im not sure exactly if im supposed to use "break" or "continue" and where their placed. if you can please answer with actual code instead of the way to do it, it would be amaizing. thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
start_time = time.time()

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)


# open page
driver.get("https://www.usmint.gov/")
while True:
    progress = do_something(
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')) #PRODUCT S
    )
except:# open page
driver.get("https://www.usmint.gov/")
else:
# product schedule
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a').click())
if progress is done
break:




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a')) #2020
    )
except:
else:
# 2020 product schedule
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cb0c26f755f49a3664c06800be"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a')) #birth set
    )
except:
else:
# birth set 2020
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cb0c26f755f49a3664c06800be"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a').click()





    '''
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="emailmodalclose"]')) #clear
    )
except:    
else:
# clear email list stupidity
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emailmodalclose"]').click()
     '''





try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]')) #add to
    )
except:
else:
# add to bag
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]").click()# double qoutes?





try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a')) #checkout
    )
except:
else:
# checkout
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a').click()





try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]')) #login
    )
except:
else:
# login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]').send_keys("username")





try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]')) #Password
    )
except:
else:
# password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]').send_keys("password")




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span')) #checkout as
    )
except:
else:
    time.sleep(3)
# checkout as registered user
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span').click()




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]')) #credit card scroll
    )
except:
else:
# credit card scroll
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]').click()  # .format?




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_month"]/option[2]')) #cc exp m
    )
except:
else:
    time.sleep(3)
# cc exp month
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_month"]/option[2]').click()





try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_year"]/option[11]')) #cc exp y
    )
except:
else:
# cc exp year
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_year"]/option[11]').click()




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]')) #cvv
    )
except:
else:
# cvv
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]').send_keys("999")




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]')) #continue to final
    )
except:
else:
# continue to final review
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]').click()




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span')) #terms of use
    )
except:
else:
# terms of use button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span').click()




try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]')) #Place order
    )
except:
else:
# place order
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]').click()
print ("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
driver.quit()
print("coin purchased")


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#   order(keys)
```

[image: pycharm screen shot]**strong text**

Comment: progress = do_something( Is kind of doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code and all seem similar.

This is a code part:

```py
while True:
    progress = do_something(
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')) #PRODUCT S
    )
except:# open page
driver.get("https://www.usmint.gov/")
```

## Issue 1

Your code does not run. On your image it is clearly visible where you should start fixing this code, Pycharm highlights the error with red, you opened a parentheses which you did not close. It seems like you wanted to set the `try`/`except` block as an argument, but `progress = do_something(` is not a complete statement, `)` should precede the `try` block. You probably wanted to achieve something like this:

```py
def action1():
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')) #PRODUCT S
        )
    except:# open page
        driver.get("https://www.usmint.gov/")
```

Then you can `progress = do_something(action1)` or something.

## Issue 2

Your indentation is incorrect in line 16 if I'm interpreting correctly what you may wanted to do. You can't just add new lines anywhere, "there are rules". If you want to nest a `try`/`except` block, inside a `while` loop, follow the indentation rules:

```py
while condition:
    try:
        something()
    except Exception:
        continue
```

## Issue 3

If you have a `while True:` block, you need to have a `break` with a condition somewhere else the loop will never end. It is unclear why is there a `while` loop there at all. There is a `try` block with a `WebDriverWait` where the code waits for an element, why would you want this to execute the same code multiple times? Shouldn't the code work for the first time?

## Issue 4

The bare except is bad practice and not necessarily yields the result you would expect, also the indentation is incorrect. You won't have any information why the `try` part failed just the page will be opened. Worse if you put all this into a `while` loop and all you will see that the page will be reloaded again and again.

You probably don't want to catch all exceptions and probably you want to do different things when your xpath is broken versus the element isn't there versus a stale element exception versus the browser is not open. The right thing to do is:

```py
try:
    something(this, that)
except AttributeError as ex:
    print(f'Oh no, an attribute error, values were: {this, that}')
    magical_attr_error_fix()
except ValueError as ex:
    print(f'Yikes, a value error, values were: {this, that}')
    raise ex
```

If you fix these kind of issues in your program it will probably start do something like you'd expect. Get rid of your `while` loops.